# handle clickevent in appbar in fragments android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am facing a problem with my custom `appbar` in my `fragment` where nothing happens when I click any item in my appbar. I have followed [this document](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar) to create an appbar in my fragment but still so success.

I have **one** activity that contains only a fragment container which I switch between fragments from. In one of fragments I want to add a custom fragment owned appbar. I first created a menu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>

</menu>
```

then in my profile.xml I added a toolbar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainFragments.AddFragment">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/Bar_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/darkBlue"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

                //alot of code in between....

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_prof"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    //more stuff implemented


</RelativeLayout>
```

however, my menu does not get inflated and if i inflate it via xml nothing happens when I click on any item, what is wrong? Thanks!

here is how my profile fragment [looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9w0O.png)

**Edit**

here is full profilefragment.java:

```
package se.umu.moad0012.myservice.MainFragments;

import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.Adapters.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.MainActivity;
import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.Models.User;
import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.ProfileFragments.AboutFragment;
import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.ProfileFragments.SettingsFragment;
import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.R;
import se.umu.moad0012.myservice.StartFragments.LoginFragment;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private RoundedImageView mProfileRoundedImageView;
    private TextView mPosts, mFollowers, mFollowing, mUserName;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private String profileId;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private ViewPager2 mViewPager2;
    private final String[] titles = new String[]{"Posts", "Reviews"};
    private final int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_grid, R.drawable.feedback};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        //declare variables
        declareVariables(v);

        //adapter for viewpager2
        mViewPager2.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(this));

        //configure tabs here
        tabMediator();

        //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        //set profile info
        setProfileInfo();

        return v;
    }

    private void tabMediator() {
        new TabLayoutMediator(mTabLayout, mViewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                tab.setText(titles[position]);
                tab.setIcon(icons[position]);
            }
        }).attach();
    }

    private void setProfileInfo() {
        mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(profileId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                mUserName.setText(user.getUsername());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void declareVariables(View v) {
        mViewPager2 = v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_profile);
        mTabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_profile);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mUserName = v.findViewById(R.id.userNameProfileFragment);
        mFollowers = v.findViewById(R.id.followers);
        mPosts = v.findViewById(R.id.posts);
        mFollowing = v.findViewById(R.id.following);
        //mProfileRoundedImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        profileId = fUser.getUid();
    }

   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_prof);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.popup_menu_profile);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Log.d("TAG", "onOptionsItemSelected: settings");
                        return true;
                    case R.id.about:
                        Log.d("TAG", "onOptionsItemSelected: about");
                        return true;
                    case R.id.logout:
                        Log.d("TAG", "onOptionsItemSelected: logout");
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Edit2**

I have noticed just now that it works, just that my text is white and thus does not show up. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your fragment

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                        //handle click
                        return true;
                    case R.id.new_pic:
                        // handle here
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: gave the same result??

Comment: can you edit the question and give complete code for `ProfileFragment.java`

Comment: The thing is, my menu does not get inflated for some reason. Also, I had an error just now with different toolbar imports. I will update my question and provide full code fo my profilefragment

Comment: just added full profilefragment.java file please check it out!